# How to use Wild card field in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Could anyone please help me in extracting the records containing 'Australia' as Country, while we don't know the keys(dates) in the datemap in Mongo Query.

My sample data ....

```
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfbdf1f123ee9f1b2bb82e0"),
    "fruit" : "apple",
    "datemap" : {
        "11/26/2018" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "bbc2bb53-b7fe-43ec-9e88-38efbd69c345",
                "country" : "Denmark"
            }
        ],
            "11/27/2018" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "bbc2bb53-b7fe-43ec-9e88-38efbd68c345",
                "country" : "Norway"
            }
        ],
            "11/28/2018" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "bbc2bb54-b7fe-43ec-9e88-38efbd68c345",
                "country" : "Australia"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfbdf1f123ee9f1b2bb8245"),
    "fruit" : "Orange",
    "datemap" : {
        "11/26/2018" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "bbc2bb53-b7fe-43ec-9e88-38efbd69c345",
                "country" : "Brazil"
            }
        ],
            "11/29/2018" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "bbc2bb53-b7fe-43ec-9e88-38efbd68c345",
                "country" : "England"
            }
        ],
            "11/30/2018" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "bbc2bb54-b7fe-43ec-9e88-38efbd68c345",
                "country" : "Australia"
            }
        ]
    }
}`
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: I'm not sure this is even possible. Used to not be possible. You might end up needing to reshape your data into a more queryable form (no unpredictable keys)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could be  possible with some aggregation trick. :-)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: yeah, my mongodb knowledge is from 5 years ago. Was very different back then :)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet: let's see, maybe in 5 more years, they'll finally add some actual SQL and throw away this pile of hacks they're accumulating :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes you are right these types of things are very expensive in terms of retrieving the data. But now  mongodb is doing enhancement in its aggregation and queries. As you no join is now possible with it. But before it the people should also aware of data structure they used to store data. Using **unknown** or **dynamic** keys for the object is not a good approach as in this question OP did.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`$objectToArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to convert unknown keys into `k` `v` pair and then put a [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) condition.

Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { "country": { "$objectToArray": "$datemap" } } },
  { "$match": { "country.v.country": "Australia" } },
  { "$project": { "country": 0 }}
])
```